# In discord.net, how do I make all messages automatically deleted every minute?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

So I have a verify channel on my discord server which verifies you if you type in //verify , but I want to make it so all messages are automatically deleted every minute on that channel. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

### One minute delay

Well if you really need that 1 Minute delay you can have a List of Message Id's (ulongs). On your MessageReceived method you can do something like `if(message.Channel.Id == YOURCHANNELID) YOURMESSAGELIST.Add(message.Id);` On your Client Ready event you would start an async Timer (from System.Threading) with a delay on 1 Minute. So always on your Timer Tick:

```
  var guild = MainClass.DiscordClient.GetGuild(YOURCHANNELID);
  var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(YOURCHANNELID);
  await channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(YOURMESSAGELIST);
  YOURMESSAGELIST.Clear();
```

### Delete message when receiving

What would be way easier and probaply cleaner is deleting every message from that channel as soon as you receive it which mean that you have an if in your MessageReceived method similar to this: `if(message.Channel.Id == YOURCHANNELID) await message.DeleteAsync();`

I hope that helps you.